# How to run LuaJIT bytecode generated from `luajit -bl`?

Tags: luajit

I have a LuaJIT function in binary bytecode format (i.e. I can run it with `luajit`)

I ran `luajit -bl` on it to convert it to text bytecode, and I rewrote some of the bytecode.

How can I run the modified text bytecode?

For example, here's an excerpt from my text bytecode

```
-- BYTECODE -- innerfunction:0-0
0001    IST          1
0002    JMP      2 => 0004
0003    KSHORT   1   0
0004 => GGET     2   0      ; "pairs"
0005    MOV      3   0
0006    CALL     2   4   2
0007    ISNEXT   5 => 0080
0008 => GGET     7   1      ; "type"
0009    MOV      8   5
0010    CALL     7   2   2
0011    ISNES    7   2      ; "string"
0012    JMP      7 => 0019
0013    GGET     7   2      ; "string"
0014    TGETS    7   7   3  ; "format"
0015    KSTR     8   4      ; "%q"
```

Comment: You'd need a LuaJIT assembler to convert the assembly to bytecode. I don't think such a program exists. You might be better off editing the bytecode directly in a hex editor.

Comment: That seems to be the case. I'll accept it as an answer.